# plotting of matlab function

Tags: matlab, plot

let us consider following picture

[image]

i wrote following code

```
>> t=-0.01:0.005:0.02;
>> y=cos(2*pi*100*t);
>> plot(t,y)
```

and got result

[image]

why it is so rough picture?also i have sampled it

```
>> t=0:Ts:0.02;
>> y=cos(2*pi*100*t);
>> plot(t,y)
```

i have got following picture

[image]

this seems ok,but about first one how can i make it more smooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are plotting from `-0.01` to `0.02` with a step of `0.005`, so that's only 7 data points. No wonder why your plot isn't smooth...

You need to refine your sampling by changing your `0.005` step to something much smaller. Start with `0.001` for example (that will give you 5 times more data points) and experiment until you are satisfied with the result:

```
t=-0.01:0.001:0.02;
```